# batch/multi with redis to sum different keys

Tags: ruby, redis

I know that using multi the execution of the redis commands is delayed until the block is finished.

How can I use multi (or similar) to send one redis request, yet still be able to calculate using the data returned?

example - user has many friends. Each friend has its own set of friends. I want to count how many friends of friends (with duplication) each user has

```
$redis.multi do
  friends_of_friends = user.friends.map(&:friends_count)
end

friend_of_friends.inject(&:+)
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

What is the primary goal that you're trying to achieve? MULTI/EXEC ensure that the bulk of commands are executed as one block (i.e. atomically) - so trying to read and then do a write based on the response isn't possible.

The way to do this with Redis is to use the `WATCH` directive to get optimistic locking - the EXEC will error if WATCHed keys are changed. Alternatively, you should consider using a Lua script to embed the read & write logic - this will ensure atomicity, will require a single request to Redis and will save the network overhead.